# Marketing Cloud Connector permission issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I recently got an admin access to salesfroce crm and i wanted to test the marketing cloud connector by sending out an email from crm. I clicked on the email send and clicked on new. After some time i got an error

> "Insufficient User Permissions, You have not been designated as a
>   Marketing Cloud Connector user. Please contact your system
>   administrator."

i went to setup to check if i have a marketing user checkbox checked or not. And i could see that it was already checked but still i was receiving the above error.

Any resolution for this?

Comment: Do you have a Salesforce Marketing Cloud User account too? And are both CRM and SFMC integrated?

Comment: Yes @TonEco both are integrated.

Comment: Do you get any type of error when trying to open the Marketing Cloud tab found in CRM (or the "Configure Marketing Cloud Connector" link on this page?  Also, did you setup Connected App Authentication per the online instructions?

Comment: @DavidDevoy I get that exact same error when opening the Marketing Cloud tab. This is when I'm trying to upgrade my Marketing Cloud Connector as in this link https://sfdc.co/MCC . 
Installed: Marketing Cloud (213.0) New Version: Marketing Cloud (213.0) but the package components are all outdated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are likely missing the user permissions "Marketing Cloud for AppExchange User" and "Marketing Cloud for AppExchange Admin". Even if the user is not integrated on the Marketing Cloud side, you should be able to access the Marketing Cloud tab. Without the above permissions, however, you will get the error

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_apply_admin_permissions.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good video that walks you through the process. Ensure you didn't miss a step somewhere. 
http://salesforce.vidyard.com/watch/jM6xwurF_qjyAT_Tt42-iA

Answer (score 0):

There's a [separate page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_troubleshoot_user_access_and_permissions.htm&type=5) in official documentation portal about it.

This error will also come up if you do not have the Permission Sets assigned and your Marketing Cloud and Sales Cloud user accounts are not [integrated](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_manage_users.htm&type=5).

Once these are all set, this message should not appear anymore.